# Mongoose findOne always return undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When ever i tried to post this API via postman using email and password.

I get **User Not Found**. I cross checked email and password 100+ times.

In command prompt i am getting **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.**

What i am doing wrong here. Please tell me, Thank you in advance.

```
exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
    try{
      const user = await userTable.findOne({ email:req.body.email });
      if (!user){
        res.send({
          status: 404,
          message: "User Not Found"
        });
      }

      const hashpass = cryptr.decrypt(user.password);
      if (hashpass == req.body.password){

        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ id: user._id, email: user.email }, process.env.JWT_PASS, {expiresIn:"1d"});
        res.send({
          status: 200,
          data: user,
          jwt: accessToken
        });
      }else{
        res.send({
          status: 404,
          message: "Wrong password"
        });
      }
    }catch(err){
      res.status(500).send({
        status: 0,
        message: "catch issue" + err.message
      });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is happening because your handler continues after sending a response, therefore attempting to modify a response after it's already been sent.

Keep in mind, it could be how you are using the `loginUser` function. If you wouldn't mind updating your question showing us how you are using it, that would be super helpful!

There are a couple things that come to mind; 1. You may need to add a return statement somewhere, like on line 10/11 for example 2. You could also wrap the code after the first `if` statement inside an `else` statement to see if that changes things.

At the end of the day, I'm pretty sure your code is continuing after sending a response, which is why you see that error.

##### With `return`

```js
exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let dataToSend = {};
    const user = await userTable.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) {
      res.send({
        status: 404,
        message: "User Not Found",
      });
      // Try adding this
      return;
    }
    const hashpass = cryptr.decrypt(user.password);
    if (hashpass == req.body.password) {
      const accessToken = jwt.sign({ id: user._id, email: user.email }, process.env.JWT_PASS, { expiresIn: "1d" });
      res.send({
        status: 200,
        data: user,
        jwt: accessToken,
      });
    } else {
      res.send({
        status: 404,
        message: "Wrong password",
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      status: 0,
      message: "catch issue" + err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

##### Wrap in `else`

This is very ugly and should only be used to test in my opinion!

```js
exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await userTable.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) {
      res.send({
        status: 404,
        message: "User Not Found",
      });
    } else {
      const hashpass = cryptr.decrypt(user.password);
      if (hashpass == req.body.password) {
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ id: user._id, email: user.email }, process.env.JWT_PASS, { expiresIn: "1d" });
        res.send({
          status: 200,
          data: user,
          jwt: accessToken,
        });
      } else {
        res.send({
          status: 404,
          message: "Wrong password",
        });
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      status: 0,
      message: "catch issue" + err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: still stuck at "User Not Found" sir

Comment: after the `await userTable.findOne(..)` can you do a `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: thank you so much sir,
i got empty object, i checked postman, changed conent-type to json.

Comment: nice! that resolved it for you?

Comment: yes sir, i never knew when the postman's content-type auto changed.
by the way thank you so much for console.log(req.body)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it. Please make sure to mark my answer as the accepted answer if it helped you :) doing so helps me :)